# how to access structure element in another file?

Tags: c, struct

how to access structure element in another file? have to file lets say 1.cpp and 2.cpp and i am comiling both file at once like gcc 1.cpp 2.cpp but i am getting error as below

```
 1. warning: ‘struct st’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 2. warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
 3.dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

please help me to fix my code is below

1.c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
struct st
{
        int s;
        char ch[20];
};
void fn(struct st *);
int main()
{
       struct st var={2,"pravu"};
       fn(&var);
}
```

2.c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  void fn(struct st *p)
{
    printf("%d\n",p->x);
    printf("%s\n",p->ch);
 }
```

I am compiling as gcc 1.c 2.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the definition of your struct in a header file. That way all c/cpp files will use the same definition; like this:

2.h

```
#ifndef 2_H_
#define 2_H_

struct st
{
        int s;
        char ch[20];
};
void fn(struct st *);

#endif
```

1.c

```
#include "2.h"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
       struct st var={2,"pravu"};
       fn(&var);
}
```

2.c

```
#include "2.h"
void fn(struct st *p)
{
    printf("%d\n",p->x);
    printf("%s\n",p->ch);
 }
```

**EDIT**: NOTE that I also moved your "forward declaration" of the function `fn(struct st *p)` in the header file. That is better practice...

**EDIT2**: I took into account the remarks of @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Note that (a) the header should have guards in it to protect it against multiple inclusion, (b) the header should not include `<stdio.h>` as none of the declarations in the header depend on declaratios from `<stdio.h>` (but this would change if, for example, you had `void ffn(FILE *fp, struct st *p);` as a declaration -- then you would need `#include <stdio.h>`.  Headers should be self-contained and idempotent.  Self-contained means that if a program needs the services declared by the header, it includes the header and no other header need be included by the code using it.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ Idempotence means that the header can be included multiple times and the compilation will not break.  That normally means it is protected by the `#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED` and `#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED` at the top and by `#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED` at the bottom.  The name chosen for the macro needs to be unique -- some people use a UUID, for example -- but otherwise is not critical.